# Unable to login as jenkins user

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to setup Jenkins for one of my projects but get this host key verification failed error.

Now, I'm trying to setup an SSH key for my Jenkins user but have issues logging as Jenkins user.

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

When I try the above command it takes me to

```
bash-4.1$
```

instead of the bash user.

Answer (score 0):

This does not tell us that you are not logged in as user `jenkins`. Check with `whoami` or `id` what user you are logged in as.

What this bash prompt shows, is just that bash (and it's prompt) uses a default configuration, because it's simply not configured to look nice/useful (empty bash configuration or perhaps it's even not available).

Comment: I have logged in as root.

Comment: How about `sudo -u jenkins /bin/bash`?

Comment: Same issue. It takes me to bash-4.1$

Comment: And did you look up if `whoami` says `jenkins` after the suggested command?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually in as the jenkins user, you are just seeing a different prompt because of the jenkins' user bash profile.

As others suggest, type:

```
whoami
```